# Redirect to URL with Bearer Token in Angular

Tags: angular

I am working with a third party who has asked to generate a token with their API. Once i receive token I have to post and navigate to their html page with Authorization header "Bearer token".

I tried the following it does nothing

```
navigateOutTokenized(url:string,token:string){
const headers=new HttpHeaders()
.append("Authorization",token);//token already as the "Bearer " attached to it
const httpOptions = {headers};
this.http.post(url,{'headers':headers});
}
```

Comment: Hi , did you try like that ? ```let headers=new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.append("Authorization",token);```

Comment: I will try and let us know here

Answer (score 1):

POST and navigate is not the same thing.
since it'a s POST request, the second parameter is the post data, in your case maybe `null` idk... or maybe you want a GET request instead?

If you want a post request you need to subscribe otherwise the method wont be executed:

```js
this.http.post(url, null, {'headers':headers});.subscribe(
res => {console.log(res)},
err => {console.error(err)}
);
```

Comment: But it needs to navigate as well. Is there a way to navigate to that url with headers